# What does this shell command do?

Tags: shell, gnu

I'm re-writing GNU's `wc` utility in a different language, and I ran across this command which *should* cause wc to output 0 bytes counted.

`(dd ibs=99k skip=1 count=0; ./wc -c) < /etc/group`

As I currently understand it, `dd` is started in a separate (sub) shell, then `wc` is started, and then the contents of `/etc/group` are redirected inside the shell?

The `dd` command uses an input block size of 99kB and skips one of those before reading the input? That's where I get tripped up.

Right now my version reports ~980 bytes read, so I'd like to better understand this command so my utility can reflect that.

Comment: Is your `/etc/group` file ~980 bytes large?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command `(dd ibs=99k skip=1 count=0; ./wc -c) < /etc/group` spawns a sub-shell (for the `(list)`) and attached `/etc/group` to that sub-shells standard input.

Inside that sub-shell the `dd` command is run (and inherits the sub-shell's standard input) with an input block size of `99k` a skip count of 1 and blocks to copy count of 0. That will cause `dd` to seek `99k` into its standard input stream and stop. When that is finished `wc` is then run (and inherits the sub-shell's standard input) and reports the number of characters left in the stream to be read (which, for all but **enormous** groups files will be nothing).

Is your `wc` implementation seeking back to the start of the file handle?

Comment: My wc implementation is not. Thank you :) I'll accept the answer once I'm allowed to.

Comment: Oh, weird @jm666. (dd ibs=99k skip=1 count=0; wc -c) < /etc/group for me shows 0 bytes counted by wc

Comment: @jm666 Even with the skip? Because that's not what I see here. What `dd` are you using? (I'm not at all certain what `dd` is supposed to do there but I would imagine it should seek and stop which is what I see.)

Comment: it is **strange**. I'm using OS X. The system default `wc` returns 2317 and the `gwc` (GNU wc) return 0. Really strange.

Comment: @jm666 here's os x's wc utility: https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/usr.bin/wc/wc.c?view=co

Answer (score 1):

The `dd` command is used with `/etc/group` as input. With those arguments, we have a block file of `99k`, 1 block of `99k` is skipped due to the `ibs argument`and then 0 blocks of `99k` are copied. Then you are using your custom command `./wc -c` with the result of this command as input. What dd achieves in the end is to to ignore a block of `99k` and then feed the remaining data into your custom command.

e.g.

```
$ wc -c /etc/group
1011 /etc/group
$ (dd ibs=500 skip=1 count=0; wc -c) < /etc/group
511
```

Of course you'll expect different results through your custom `wc` command.

Answer (score 0):

Beware, it depends of the implementation

Using the @nalipar's example on my OS X.

```
$ wc -c /etc/group
    2317 /etc/group

$ gwc -c /etc/group #the GNU version of the wc
2317 /etc/group
```

the system default `wc`

```
(dd ibs=500 skip=1 count=0; wc -c) < /etc/group
```

prints

```
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes transferred in 0.000012 secs (0 bytes/sec)
    2317
```

using the GNU `wc`

```
(dd ibs=500 skip=1 count=0; gwc -c) < /etc/group
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes transferred in 0.000013 secs (0 bytes/sec)
1817
```